# How to switch binding in runtime (Camel Rest Dsl)

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a rest endpoint with binding mode set to off:

```
rest("/users")
   .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off)
      .get()
      .route()
      .id("Get all users")
        .bean(userService,"getAll")
.endRest()
```

I want to switch binding mode to json when an exception is caught:

```
 onException(UserNotFoundException.class)
   .handled(true)
   .process(responseProcessor);
```

How to do that with camel? I've tried to set header CamelBinding to json but this doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that. In your processor in the onException you can set the response payload to JSon yourself. And you can use Camel's dataformat / components for JSon support if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the binding mode with this command, in the process method:

```
@Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
exchange.getContext().getRestConfiguration().setBindingMode(RestConfiguration.RestBindingMode.json);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this may change binding mode for other endpoints as well. I wanted to apply this to a single endpoint.

Comment: Well this will change the binding mode for the context of the route in which the processor is called, so for that execution only. Since you have the .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off) at the initial route, for the next request it will again be set to off.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and clarification. That is what I needed(binding for a single execution). Will test it later and give you feedback.